# Read password protected MS-Word files

Tags: r, ms-word, passwords

I have a folder of ~200 MS-word files I would like to read into R. An unknown proportion of these files have been password protected (the passwords follow a simple month-quarter rule so I am able to work them out individually to open the files), which is making it tricky to get them into R. Ideally I am looking for a method that would allow me to read in all the files into R without opening each one in MS-word to remove the password.

I have been using the `read_docx` and `read_dir` functions (for individual and multiple files, respectively) in the `textreadr` package but this does not seem to have a provision for passwords in the same way that the `excel.link` package does.

Any other package/function recommendations would be much appreciated.